# Однородные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли считать однородными следующие определения, учитывая сходство производимого ими впечатления?

Современным  высокоэффективным оборудованием; новое высокотехнологичное оборудование.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это неоднородные определения. Определение ''Современным'' относится к словосочетанию  высокоэффективным оборудованием''. Здесь нет никакого общего впечатления. Во втором примере запятая между неоднородными определениями возможна, она придает пояснительный характер.
Ср.: новое высокотехнологичное оборудование (к имевшимся высокотехнологичным оборудованиям прибавились еще одни высокотехнологичные оборудования);  новое,  высокотехнологичное оборудование  ( до этого  высокотехнологичных оборудований не было).
См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Не-е-ет. Это надо уж очень захотеть. ))